# Security bug with files uploaded to server - java ee - tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I'm trying to build a web app, that can upload a file to my server, and get a link for downloading later.

I make the two tings rigth with the next code:

```
    String subirArchivo(int codigo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    Part filePart = request.getPart("archivo"); // Obtiene el archivo
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.

    //InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream(); //Lo transforma en InputStream

    String path="/archivos/";
    File uploads = new File(path); //Carpeta donde se guardan los archivos
    uploads.mkdirs(); //Crea los directorios necesarios
    File file = File.createTempFile("cod"+codigo+"-", "-"+fileName, uploads); //Evita que hayan dos archivos con el mismo nombre

    try (InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream()){
        Files.copy(input, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }

    return file.getPath();
}
```

As the files are uploaded into C:\archivos, I had to add

```
<Context docBase="C:\archivos" path="/archivos" />
```

inside server.xml from tomcat config.

The problem is that the user can upload a file and **execute it**. For example, if he uploads a .jsp file, when a user calls it, is executed by the server

My question is. how to solve that?

Comment: You must not add `C:\archivos` as a context. Instead add a servlet that just copies files from the file system, mapping *itself* from e.g. `http://yourserver/archivos/aaa/bbb.pdf` to `C:\archivos\aaa\bbb.pdf`. Searching for *java file servlet* will provide many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thans to nikos-paraskevopoulos, I found how to upload and download my file in the rigth way:

upload:

```
    String subirArchivo(int codigo, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    Part filePart = request.getPart("archivo"); // Obtiene el archivo
    String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); // MSIE fix.

    if(!fileName.isEmpty()){
        String path="/archivos/";
        File uploads = new File(path); //Carpeta donde se guardan los archivos
        uploads.mkdirs(); //Crea los directorios necesarios
        File file = File.createTempFile("cod"+codigo+"-", "-"+fileName, uploads); //Evita que hayan dos archivos con el mismo nombre

        try (InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream()){
            Files.copy(input, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

        return file.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Post link:

```
if(adjunto!=null){
                String filename=adjunto.substring(10); //La longitud de /archivos/
                String borrar="<a href=borrarServlet?codigo="+codigo+"&comentario="+idComentario+"&file="+filename+"><img width=\"16\" src=images/borrar.png></img></a>";
                comentarios+="<tr><td>"+fecha+"</td>"+"<td>"+texto+"<br><a class=\"adj\" href=."+adjunto+">Descargar archivo</a></td><td>"+borrar+"</td></tr>";
            }
```

Download:

```
String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo().substring(1), "UTF-8");
File file = new File("/archivos", filename);
response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(filename));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
```